# Prove function in little-oh of a big-theta function

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis

I'm having trouble with this homework question.

Prove if $f(n)$ is $o( g(n) )$ and $g(n)$ is $\Theta( h(n) )$, then $f(n)$ is $o(h(n))$.

I know I need to use the precise definition of a limit, but I'm not sure how to apply it to this proof. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(n)$ is $o( g(n) )$

This above equation implies the following:

$f(n) < c \cdot g(n) \  -(1)$

for some $c \in R$ and $\forall n \geq n_{0}$

$g(n)$ is $\Theta( h(n) )$

The above equation implies following:

$ c_{1} \cdot h(n) \leq g(n) \leq c_{2} \cdot h(n) -(2)$

for some $c1, c2 \in R$ and $\forall n \geq n_{0}'$

Now let's assume $c$ > 0

Multiplying equation $(2)$ by $c$ gives:

$ c \cdot c_{1} \cdot h(n) \leq c \cdot g(n) \leq c \cdot c_{2} \cdot h(n)$

Considering right side of the above inequality:

$c \cdot g(n) \leq c \cdot c_{2} \cdot h(n)  -(3)$

Let $n_{0}''$ be $max(n_{0}, n_{0}')$

We can say $\forall n \geq n_{0}''$, equation $(1)$, $(2)$ and $(3)$ will hold true. Now by using $(1)$ and $(3)$, we can infer:

$ c \cdot c_{2} \cdot h(n) > f(n) -(4)$

Let $c' = c \cdot c_{2}$

Therefore we can write equation $(4)$ as:

$ f(n) < c' \cdot h(n)$

$\forall n \geq n_{0}''$ and since $R$ is closed under multiplication, therefore $c \in R$

which implies $f(n)$ is $o(h(n))$.

Note: For $c < 0$, you can consider left side of the inequality, which after multiplying by $c$ will actually come to right side (since $c < 0$).

Comment: Doesn't little-oh imply that $ f(n) <= c g(n) $ @Lashit Jain ?

Comment: @TylerP little-oh implies $f(n) < cg(n)$, it's the big-oh which implies $f(n) \leq cg(n)$.